# Simulate MQTT connection

Tags: node.js, mqtt, iot, mosquitto

I'm doing a project in which I, alongside a partner, need to make an intelligent lock. The lock communicates with the broker, mosquitto in this case, and the broker communicates with the backend of the software. The backend sends the confirmation to the lock through the broker and a notification to the frontend through socket.io. Or, at least, thats whats its supposed to do. However, nor do I have the prototype lock to use, nor have I ever dealt with MQTT before. What I'm looking for is a way to "simulate a connection" where I can send data as the lock would. That way I'll be able to proceed on programming.

Comment: Why "simulate" a connection? Why not just use a real MQTT connection? An MQTT broker is trivial to set up, and there are free ones on the Internet that you can use (CloudMQTT, for instance). Also socket.io is unnecessary with MQTT and will just needlessly complicate things.

Comment: @romkey Thanks for your answer. I'll try and use CloudMQTT. Sorry for using the word "simulate". I couldn't think of a better way to explain what I wanted to do.

Comment: Hey it's okay - a lot of the time people would use some kind of protocol simulator. I hope CloudMQTT works okay for you. I've used their free tier several times. Good luck!

Comment: @romkey Hello again. It would appear that the CloudMQTT free plan is only available in the US (I'm Brazilian), or, otherwise, no longer existes, according to one of their posts made in February. Do you have any other suggestions that I could try?

Comment: Anytime you are not using the "real" thing, you are simulating. Simulations come in many flavors, eg. Microsoft Flight Simulator vs. NASA Flight Simulator. Google "MQTT Simulator" for your choices, including our product.

Comment: @GambitSupport Thanks. I'll be trying the software from Gambit Communications then.